# Move Grid across Progress Bar value

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I try to create simple text and move in across my `Progress Bar` value so icreated `Progree Bar` and `Grid` with `TextBlock`:

```
<Controls:MetroProgressBar
    Name="progressBar"
    Width="500"
    Height="2"
    Value="0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"             
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="Gray"
    Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
<Grid Name="myGrid" Margin="0,0,0,0">
<TextBlock
    Name="tbTest"
    Text="{Binding ElementName=progressBar, Path=Value}"
    Foreground="White"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"             
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="16"
    Margin="255,-35,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

Now inside my Timer Event i am changing my `ProgressBar` value and try to move my `Grid`:

```
if (progressBar.Value < 100)
{
    progressBar.Value += 10;
    Grid grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(progressBar, 0) as Grid;
    if (grid != null)
    {
        var decorator = grid.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "PART_Indicator");
        if (decorator != null)
            myGrid.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(decorator.ActualWidth, myGrid.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY);
    }
}
```

Now although `grid` variable not null my `TextBlock` still now moving.

Answer (score 0):

What you have works, you just weren't seeing it because of the `TextBlock`'s margin. If you get rid of that then it moves, whether or not it is doing exactly what you want, I'm not sure.

I'd suggest cleaning up the XAML some, margins are a good thing, but can lead to hard to find issues. I'd suggest wrapping the `ProgressBar` and `Grid` in a `StackPanel` and removing the margins from everything.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid Name="myGrid">
        <TextBlock Name="tbTest"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="16"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=progressBar,
                                  Path=Value}" />
    </Grid>
    <ProgressBar Name="progressBar"
                 Width="500"
                 Height="2"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Foreground="Gray"
                 Value="0" />
</StackPanel>
```

I left the rest of your code intact and it worked.